# DRCSIM: Can't figure out how to run Gazebo on remote machine and get vision input

Tags: cloudsim

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

I want to set up Gazebo to run remotely on one machine, and do control from another machine (the DRCSIM setup). This seems to run into a problem which must have been solved in cloudsim: how does the rendering for the simulated cameras get done? Whose GPU is used (the remote gazebo machine or the local ROS machine)?
Note I am not trying to run a gzclient at all. I want ROS to work over the network (which it seems to do just fine). I can't get gzserver to simulate cameras when launched remotely.

If I log in on the console of machine 1 and type

```
source /usr/local/share/drcsim/setup.sh
roslaunch atlas_utils qual_task_1.launch
```

on machine 1 and run something that just displays images from the topic
/multisense_sl/camera/left/image_raw on machine 2, everything works fine. I see the robot on machine 1's display and the simulated camera view of gates on machine 2.

If I log in on the console of machine 1 and run a gzserver instead:

```
source /usr/local/share/drcsim/setup.sh
roslaunch atlas_utils qual_task_1.launch gzname:=gzserver
```

on machine 1 and run something that just displays images from the topic
/multisense_sl/camera/left/image_raw on machine 2, everything works fine. I see no client or image on machine 1 and the simulated camera view of gates on machine 2.

If I try to use machine 1 remotely I fail.
First without trying to own the display:

```
ssh machine1
source /usr/local/share/drcsim/setup.sh
roslaunch atlas_utils qual_task_1.launch gzname:=gzserver
```

I get the error message:

```
Error [RenderEngine.cc:608] Can't open display: 
Warning [RenderEngine.cc:87] Unable to create X window. Rendering will be disabled
Error [MultiCameraSensor.cc:81] Unable to create MultiCameraSensor. Rendering is disabled.
```

I can rostopic echo /clock on machine 2, but I can't view the images.

Using -X (which should be irrelevant because I want to own machine 1's display. I am not displaying anything from machine 1 directly on machine 2).

```
ssh machine1 -X
source /usr/local/share/drcsim/setup.sh
roslaunch atlas_utils qual_task_1.launch gzname:=gzserver
```

I get the same error message, and
I can rostopic echo /clock on machine 2, but I can't view the images.

Okay. Now I leave myself logged on to the console of machine 1, which I don't want to do since I want others to be able to use Gazebo remotely on this machine.
Logging in with ssh with and without -X work as long as I say on machine1:

```
export DISPLAY=machine1:0.0
```

This does not work if someone else is logged in on the console of machine 1 and owns the display, or if no one is logged in to the console of machine 1 (including me).
I get the error message:

```
Error [RenderEngine.cc:608] Can't open display: machine1:0.0
Warning [RenderEngine.cc:87] Unable to create X window. Rendering will be disabled
Error [MultiCameraSensor.cc:81] Unable to create MultiCameraSensor. Rendering is disabled.
```

So how does this work in Cloudsim?
Chris

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/2153/drcsim:-can%27t-figure-out-how-to-run-gazebo-on-remote-machine-and-get-vision-input./) by [cga](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/66/cga/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 223 on 2013-03-31

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

You can see how CloudSim does it in [startup_scripts.py](https://bitbucket.org/osrf/cloudsim/src/default/cloudsimd/launchers/launch_utils/startup_scripts.py?at=default).  Search for "nvidia" and then start reading.  Basically, we:

- install nvidia drivers
- configure X to use nvidia drivers
- configure lightdm to auto-login a particular user, which is the user we'll be running Gazebo as via ssh later

Then, even on reboot, your chosen user will be logged in, owning the X display.  The last step is, when ssh'ing in, set your DISPLAY explicitly:

```
export DISPLAY=:0
```

---

Originally posted by [gerkey](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/74/gerkey/) with karma: 1414 on 2013-04-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2